# Kiosk type machine - Guess account good start

Tags: boot, 14.04, encryption, guest-session, kiosk

I have some public use PC's currently setup with 14.04 64bit using the guest account to automatically boot and login. It's working fine, but I'd like to make it even more restricted. Meaning I'd like to be sure no one sitting in front of the PC can change anything even if they find a way to boot from a USB drive.

Encrypting the full install of Ubuntu seems like the right path, but that requires either a person to provide a password (and thus can then decrypt and make changes if they were to boot from USB) or use a key file. If it's a key file, then it has to be on the PC itself and if someone looks at the GRUB startup they can see exactly which file is the key, then the system is vulnerable.

Of course I've disabled any BIOS options available for booting anything but the hard drive, but it's a mix of older computers and not all BIOS's have the same options or the same level of security. ie, you can turn off the option to boot to USB, but can still hit a key to access a boot menu where it will gladly let you boot to USB. These are donated PC's and there's no budget to replace them with something more security conscious.

Again, the guest account is wonderful. I've setup a basic user, linked it to the guest skel directory so I can set the basic user up and then the guest account copies the basic user account on logon. The guest account also provides a good level of restriction, there's just simply no permission to even view some things that a normal user can. I just need an extra layer to prevent people, whom are allowed to sit and do nothing in front of a computer all day, from bypassing startup and using anything other than the guest account.

I still want/need automatic updates to run and be installed. Otherwise I would just have the system pull from a read only image each time it boots.

tl;dr Is there any way to protect a system from modification without having to supply a password on startup? Setup as a public terminal so that idle hands cannot bypass the boot process and modify the installed OS?

Comment: Regarding being able to log in into other accounts, you could edit `/etc/passwd` and change the shell of other *user* accounts to `/bin/false`. (Note the emphasis on user.) Also, (as you probably already know) don't put them in the `sudo` group.

Comment: Here is a really great [guide](http://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/) to setting up an Ubuntu kiosk computer. I'm sure it can help you out.

Comment: @CarrotIsland yeah was made by Oli Warner. Guess who that is :=)